# How to document class reference using jsdoc

Tags: javascript, class, webstorm, jsdoc

I want to have a class/constructor reference in a variable. How to comment the following code using jsdoc to have working autocomplete in WebStorm?

```js
var DateLink = getDateConstructor();
DateLink.pa //I want to have autocomplete for parse()
```